# My mesh stretches and warps whenever I pose it?

Tags: weight-painting

[image]

This image pretty much sums it up. When ever I try to pose the head, legs, arms, etc. the model warps like this. Oddly, the mesh only warps in this direction, front to back. I hit G or R to pose it and it does this on both.
I'm pretty new to blender.

Comment: Possibly you have scaled your mesh in one direction and this is causing distortion as it is not evenly scaled. You should select the mesh and ‘Apply Scale’.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably scaled your armature on the Z axis in *Object* mode, so apply its scale in *Object* mode (or you may have stretched your bones in *Pose* mode but probably not).

You probably wanted to scale your character on the Z axis but it's not the way to do it, you need to select your mesh and scale it in *Edit* mode to do so, then change the bones size in *Edit* mode as well.